# changing formatted "25%" in "25 %"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've formatted following string

```
Formatted = "My profit is {:.0%}."
print(Formatted.format(0.25))
```

The output is : `My profit is 25%.`
How can I change the output into : `My profit is 25 %`.

I've allready added (between 25 and %):  "," "space" ":" "() and other things but it always give an error.

Thanks beforhand for your help.

Comment: Put the percent symbol in the regular string, *outside* the format specification.

Comment: This does not seem to be possible with the `%` [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#formatspec), so you'll have to do it manually with the `%` outside of the `{...}` and the value x100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.replace()`

```
Formatted = "My profit is {:.0%}."
print(Formatted.format(0.25).replace('%', ' %'))
```

or

```
formatted = "My profit is {:.0%}.".format(0.25).replace('%', ' %')
print(formatted)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `%` formatter does not have any options to add spacing.

You can use the `f` formatter instead, multiply the value by 100, and add the `%` character (with space) after the formatted value:

```
value = 0.25
Formatted = "My profit is {:.0f} %."
print(Formatted.format(value * 100))
```

If your string template doesn't need to by dynamic, you can combine the multiplication with the string format by using an f-string, which lets you use an expression inside of placeholders:

```
value = 0.25
print(f"My profit is {value * 100:.0f} %.")
```